# Unallocated space with important data

Tags: gparted, data-recovery, testdisk

I used GParted to convert a primary partition to extended one after copying the data to another partition. After having the extended partition I moved the data back. To my utter shock after a restart I found out that the new extended partition did convert into "unallocated space". I tried installing `testdisk`. Testdisk could identify the partition as a primary partition and not the newly created extended partition. So what should I do now? I badly want the data back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather difficult to solve such problems via the internet, and it certainly doesn't fit the *question -> answer* nature of askubuntu.com.

Anyways:

- Whenever such things happen, immediately shutdown the system and don't write (or install) anything to it!
- Start a live CD, download the 6.12-WIP version of [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) (you just need to unpack it, then start it with `sudo ./testdisk`), let it search for partitions, examine the contents of the found partitions, and if you are **100%** sure that you've found the right partition, restore it.
- You can find a couple of detailed examples in the [TestDisk wiki](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk#Documentation) (e.g., [TestDisk step-by-step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)).

**If you don't feel comfortable doing it yourself**, ask someone that has experience with this tool to do it for you. Any mistake can lead to permanent loss of data!

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone is willing to spend *a lot* of time explaining the process in detail, you're best bet will be researching this yourself online.  [Here's an excellent lifehacker article](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/04/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) which guides you a process very similar to the position you're in.

I've used the tools outlined in that article myself and while it takes a bit of reading to get started, it's not particularly complicated and I got good results.

There used to be a good WIKI page on wiki.ubuntu.com regarding disk forensics, but I can't seem to find it anymore.  I'll post it if I can find it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Comment: Not something I'm interested in doing to an answer I provided nearly 18 months ago to a guy desperate for data back same day. And as my answer clearly stated, a full expose of the article's relevant points would fill pages. When the question is time-sensitive or vague this canned request makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you got easily recognizable data on your partition (pictures, documents, file archives etc) I would recommend you trying out [foremost](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/foremost.1.html), it has helped me out a few times.

Also, check out [DataRecovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).