# How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bits

I accidentally deleted a **NTFS** 255 GB partition using **Gparted**, and yes it contains **LOTS** of important data.

Upon realizing the deletion I haven't yet created any file-system on it. So it still shows Unallocated.

[image]

I tried **Testdisk** , but it shows entire partitions created from the beginning.

This **sdb** is my secondary drive with Xubuntu and Kubuntu on it. And that 255 GB NTFS  partition was cross platform storage drive.

I am currently in **sda** with Ubuntu and Win7 in dual boot, which enables me to use it as Safe recovery option rather then Live USB drive.

**First** ,  should i allocate it to ? file-System for better recovery .

**Second** , i really need to recover data from this drive so please give me possible  suggestions and proven methods of data recovery.

**Third** ,does **Testdisk** requires deleted partition to be allocated for its recovery .

I am currently trying the answer seen here https://askubuntu.com/a/24951/63025 with Testdisk scanning for partition second time, hoping to recover it.

It looks a duplicate but i can't confirm if the OP got it right. Since my first doubt is to **allocate** it or not.

If any clarification required please do comment ,i will add it.

**Edit:** TestDisk deeper search results.

```
   The following partitions can't be recovered:
         Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
    >  HPFS - NTFS          22241 107 11 55592   3 27  535777280
       FAT32 LBA            274460 158 19 460576 228 16 2989957948

NTFS, 274 GB / 255 GiB
& for FAT32 LBA 1530 GB / 1425 GiB
```

Comment: Did you actually commit the changes? If you just delete, it will not do anything on disk until you manyally allow it to go ahead with the changes.

Comment: yes  i Deleted it , committed the Changes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well. Testdisk really works. I have documented in the past my previous 500 GB Data loss which was up to 80% recovered via Testdisk.

Take a look at this video in Youtube: [Recover deleted partitions using Testdisk in Ubuntu #11](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg).

I couldn't fully recover my data because of I was trying to recover using different tools, (including MS Based tools which I don't recommend because of it resulted in the damage of the data itself. So I strongly suggest you to first run the steps mentioned in the video in order to bring back the partition, after which you will be able to undelete/recover any data loss that could happen during data recovery.

I am following your question closely even if downvoted just in order to provide help. I know this is not a forum and have read the rules but I have experienced this in the past and I know how it feels. Just for information: It took me 2+ weeks to fully recover my data. So please be patient. I am sure we'll find a way to bring your data back.

Good luck!

Comment: Maybe giving instructions from the Testdisk wiki could help?

Comment: Yeah sure: Testdisk and useful information related can be reached clicking here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk and a step-by-step procedure with illustrations can be seen here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: I was referring to using that as documentation for your answer.

Comment: The video helped thanks , and thanks @GeppettvsD'Constanzo a lot for step-by-step link , i also posted the steps as answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/176906/63025) .

Comment: Testdisk restored absolutely restored all my customer data on the mistakenly deleted partition.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse: That's exactly what Testdisk does. BTW, I suggest you to run a backup soon. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

First you shouldn't allocate it, but even if you do, with RAW recovery it doesn't matter.  But as I said its better not to allocate, just to make it easier.

RAW recovery means to read files without reference to any operating system.  The RAW scan mode can locate the files without the aid of file system.  I would recommend Ubuntu Rescue Remix.

> Ubuntu Rescue Remix is a Linux Live CD. It already comes with a whole
>   array of data recovery tools. One of them is Ddrescue. Ddrescue, is
>   one of the best data recovery programs available and it is free.
>   Ddrescue works by extracting a raw image of your hard drive and
>   transferring it to another drive.  It extracts data bit by bit,
>   regardless of the file system on the drive. The reason it works even
>   when hard drives are dying is because Ddrescue retries several times
>   and even tries to read data backwards. The procedure sometimes can
>   take days, but it is very effective.<sup>1</sup>

[Read on](http://geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-recover-data-even-when-hard-drive-is-damaged/)

Download the ISO CD image of [Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/), burn the CD and boot the computer with it.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[GeekyProjects](http://geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-recover-data-even-when-hard-drive-is-damaged/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Mitch for alternate solution , i am using it for other Disk recovery.