# How to recover files after deleted my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, data-recovery, thinkpad, lts

I normally dual-boot with 12.04 and Win XP pro sp3 on a Thinkpad R60.  I needed to reinstall windows because of problems piling up, so I ran the computer's built-in hard-disk recovery software.  I told it not to mess with the other partitions, but somehow it deleted the Linux partition.  That's what I was using to backup all of my windows files, so now everything I have is *gone*.  I just ran the USB setup with linux, and the partition is deleted - it just shows it as empty space.

Is there ANY way to get all of my files back?

Comment: Try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), that's what I used when 2 of my partitions were accidentally deleted, it can recover deleted partitions.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend Recovery using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Boot Ubuntu from Live USB drive or CD, , run

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

[**TestDisk**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/testdisk.8) is used to recover missing partitions and repair a corrupted one. It served me well in recent past to recover entire Hard disk , so i am suggesting it.

After installing ,open Terminal and run `sudo testdisk` to get this

[image]

Select the **`create`** to create new log file ,select the Hard disk you want to recover , **`Proceed`** upon selecting the Disk

[image]

Then select the **`Intel`** option , `Enter` to proceed further.

[image]

**`Analyse`** to search for Lost Partition

[image]

Then it will list the Current Partition Structure , select the `Quick search` option to list the `Deleted partition` .

[image]

If Found Nothing then select the `Deeper search` option to list the deleted partitions. It will probably list all the partitions created since the Disk was First used. You have to be extremely careful here.

[image]

For more in-depth instructions refer this [Step-By-Step guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) .If found proper listing of partitions , select the `Write` option and Reboot to see the changes. Best of Luck .

Also refer below options before trying this above , here

[How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

[Mitch's answer here for RAW data recovery](https://askubuntu.com/a/171167/63025)

[Ubuntu help page on Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)