# Accidentally deleted all partitions, how can I restore the operating systems?

Tags: windows-7, hp, grubrescue, boot-partition

Hi guys I installed ubuntu 12.04 (x32) on my system and then side by side I had my windows7 ultimate(x64) running aswell (dual boot).

Last week for some reason I started getting a blue screen crash after running an update on ubuntu. Blue screen said it has a crash with code bCC:0000145, I didnt know what to make of it hence I thought just erase the whole HDD and start over with a fresh copy of windows. 
And this where (I feel a major disaster struck, as i'm a noob i've no clue what i did was WRONG!!!) I got into a huge problem, when I put in the Windows OEM cd and set the comp to boot from cd it was going all fine untill I deleted all my partitions into unallocated space and then wanted to make new partions and start fresh - BAMM another blue screen of death.

And this time after the blue screen it's stopped booting from Cd, and directly gave me an error message saying "no such partition; grub rescue" 
I've tried everything in my capacity to get it to work but I dont know clearly what to do further please help.

Comment: Just a thought: Start by not using capslock.

Comment: Did you try booting to an Ubuntu CD and try installing Ubuntu again?

Comment: no not yet!!! do you thing that will work with a flash drive???

Comment: If you have another system that you can use to create a bootable USB on, then yes.  [Read this page for details on creating an Ubuntu USB live environment from Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).  You'll have to still have another system you can use though to do it.

Comment: Note to everyone: If they can fix it by my comments, I will turn the comments into an answer. If not, then its part of the diagnostic process, so leave my comments be.

Comment: the lord thanks for the info... yes i do have access to another computer and creating a bootable usb

Comment: Might [TestDisk](http://askubuntu.com/a/176906/58950) launched from a LiveUSB be helpful to recover lost data? Or, perhaps it is too late now?

Comment: You can insert the Installation disc again and then using repair my computer do
recover your computer from an earlier time and then your comp is OK

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you installed grub on the master boot record.

You will need to run 
    fixmbr or fixboot 
from a windows 7 recovery command prompt (located under repair my computer on windows 7 install disc). This will remove grub from the master boot record. You will then be able to re-install windows.

Comment: thank you for your help. I'll try it and let you know if it was successful.