# Ubuntu accidentally deleted the partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, xubuntu

I my laptop i had installed ubuntu 16.04.  But accidentally all partiion are deleted. Now after reboot the system I'm getting following error.
"error no such partiion enter rescue mode ubuntu"

Anyone help my what I have to do caused tin this PC I lost my all important data.
Is there any way to get back my data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data)

Comment: What is the filesystem type of the partition that was deleted? Knowing this would greatly help you find an answer specific to your problem

Comment: See also [How to recover files after deleted my Ubuntu partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176885/how-to-recover-files-after-deleted-my-ubuntu-partition)

Comment: Andrea Corbellini , I used ext4 file system