# How to recover data from a drive that was erased during the Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

Yesterday I had two NTFS partitions on my drive. One on which Windows 7 was installed (C Drive) and the other contained my data (D Drive).

During Ubuntu installation I choose to install Ubuntu and erase my existing OS. When Ubuntu installed, I was shocked to see no partition. All my data was gone. I must have done something wrong in selecting my option during installation.

Is there any way I can recover my D Drive?

Comment: Try testdisk, once it saved my life

Comment: Has been answered before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data

Comment: Thanks Tachyons

I am not been able to run testdisk. I am following everything written in http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

After downloading, I created root account and logged in from that account. I downloaded and extracted testdisk-6.14-WIP. Afterwords I tried the command

"sudo testdisk-6.14-WIP/testdisk_static"

"command not found" returned and I am not able to go ahead with running testdisk

This is my first time using Linux so kindly guide me accordingly. I will really be grateful.

Comment: Thanks rosch for the link but in my case I have installed Ubuntu in the same partition I want to recover (since both C and D are now a single drive, no partition)

Answer (score 0):

I saw questions like that 2 times today:
Yes. You have lost them.

If you are good at linux:

1. DO NOT USE UBUNTU YOU JUST INSTALLED! (Tmp files WILL overwrite you data)
2. Make a Knoppix live CD/USB/DVD/whatever and boot from it.
3. Mount all you disks (If it didnt do it automaticaly)
4. Open up console and launch "testdisk". (You will find it easy to use)
5. Recover everything you can/want to USB or Portable HD but not to newly installed Ubuntu

But if you aren't good with Linux enough (as i see) then you better bring it to service that will do this for you.