# I think that I installed Ubuntu over my Windows 8 partitions

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 13.10

I wanted to reinstall Ubuntu 13.10, and I chose to do it over the old 13.10 Ubuntu because it had some problems. Now I can't boot Windows 8 or find it in the boot menu. And Ubuntu has all partitions of my PC.
Can I recover Windows or at least recover the files I had on Windows?

Comment: You need data recovery tools. Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206#286206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into `ubuntu os` and open the terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run the below commands on it,

```
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

After restarting,your `grub` will display windows os and you can select and boot it.The above commands will reinstall your grub to display both `windows` and `ubuntu` os's.

Comment: Doesn't work :s

Comment: try `boot-repair disk`

Comment: Already did, got this http://paste.ubuntu.com/6463867/

Comment: plz upload gparted screenshot to imgur.com and paste the link here.

Comment: there was no ntfs partition.I think your your windows os will be deleted.Anyways upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rICXvah.png

Comment: what was the other option in top right corner of gparted?

Comment: I don't think there is one

Comment: from the gparted screenshot,your windows os was accidentally deleted(there was no ntfs partition).

Comment: And is there a way that I could recover (some of) my files?

Comment: try `testdisk` it could recover files from the deleted partition.

Comment: Do I need to put this in the terminal?

Comment: see this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data

Comment: It's analysing, I'll let you know if it worked

Comment: SOrry, didn't work..

Comment: @sofboy, your Question is a bit broad. Instead of adding new information here in Comments, **edit** the Question to clarify it.