# Data of Windows Formatted during Ubuntu how to recover?

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, windows-7, system-installation, data-recovery

I am really in a big trouble i have lost my 352GBs of data during Ubuntu installation.

I mistakenly made a partition which caused to format My data which was already placed in that partition.

The data i lost during Ubuntu installation how can i recover it.

Answer (score 1):

Try  [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)to recover datas from deleted partition.

Comment: I quit the Ubuntu installation. now formatted space is un-allocated. how can i recover it

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data