# Destroyed windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, system-installation, data-recovery

My sister was trying to install ubuntu on her laptop, on partitioning time she chose the automatic resize option, the problem is that now her windows partition is lost.

I'm not sure of the options she chose but after the installation I see she has `lvm`, her windows 8 was on a dynamic partition with 2 drives on windows and that partition was her whole 750 GB Hard disk, it looks like ubuntu installer has removed the windows partition.

Is there any way I can restore her windows drives? I think ubuntu has written the `lvm` on free parts of the windows partition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The general procedure for data recovery is here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery . Get a start with that link and update your question if you have a specific problem with a specific step.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206#286206 you need to boot Ubuntu in "Try out" mode (live). Testdisk may be able to see and recover your dynamic disk partitions. Ubuntu can't deal with MS "dynamic" disks, hence the failure on installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package that you can install, and try to recover your lost data from the Windows partitions. Unfortunately, you wont be able to also recover Windows installation. You will have to install Windows again.

The package to use for recovering lost data from your Windows partitions is called 'testdisk' . You can install it with this code:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

And you can check the following links for further instructions on how to use testdisk in Ubuntu:

[How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data)

[How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)