# Windows 7 dual boot, tried installing ubuntu on top of another ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-7

So I had windwos 7 running fine and decided that I want to install ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I downloaded the image and made bootable usb drive. I then went ant clicked install ubuntu, it loaded for quite a while and then it said that I already have another ubuntu installation. Oh snap, I totally forgot about that. So I clicked erase ubuntu and reinstall. It loaded for a few minutes and then it said that non recoverable error occured. Then I restarted my PC and I got this error :

> Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected
>   boot device and press a key

I then I tried all available boot options however they all gave me the same error. I am currently on ubuntu live usb. I tried installing boot-repair and running it with the recommended settings, however it didn't fix it. What do I do now ? Tell me if you need any more information.

boot-repair pastebin :

> http://paste.ubuntu.com/7458605/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, back up all your data using the ubuntu live cd.
Next, get back your windows bootloader using these [instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/). 
Then, put in the live cd and during installation of ubuntu 14.04 don't do erase ubuntu and reinstall, instead, go to manual partitioning(or whatever similar is written there) and erase the partition where ubuntu was installed previously(you can find it by seeing the partition type as ext4 or ext3). Completely format it and install ubuntu there by selecting it and then clicking on details or change button for that partiton(where you should click on tick mark for "format?" and then select"/" in mount point).
That should solve your issue!

Comment: I clicked manual partitioning. it shows my whole harddrive now as one ext4 partition. And there's no host dir and I can't access my windows files. does it mean that my windows files are lost ?

Comment: Perhaps but you can try testdisk if you want to restore data [link1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data) [link2](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)