# Lost partitions after accidently selecting "Erase entire disk" on Ubuntu install (but did not proceed with installation)?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I had an old Ubuntu installation (version 13), which had a partitioned drive, with `/home` mounted on a partition, and `/data` on another partition which I used to store my files. I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04, but I accidently clicked on the "Erase entire disk" option, and now the old partitions are gone. I didn't proceed with the installation, so I except it to be recoverable. How can I recover what I had on `/data`?

Note that unlike a [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data), I'm not sure what filesystem `/data` was. It could have been NTFS, but more probably it was ext4.

Thanks.

Comment: @RodSmith I don't know if the partition is `NTFS` or `ext4`.

Comment: Try to use boot-repair, i suppose your disks has not been erased as the disks are erased when one proceeds with installation

Comment: @ubuntu99 Can you give more details? I don't know how to use boot-repair.

Comment: @becko instructions for boot-repair has been given in the answer

Comment: Why the close votes? I think this question is different from the supposed duplicate.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the filesystem is, within a wide range (something *really* exotic wouldn't be found by TestDisk). If you Try TestDisk and it doesn't work, you can ask again with more details. Unless and until you try it, though, your question is similar enough to the earlier one that I continue to think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Different question, same answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#463094

Answer (score 0):

Boot Ubuntu 14.04 using a live media like USB stick or DVD then open terminal and execute following commands one by one :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then use recommended repair and see if problem is solved, if it does not solve you problem, then upload boot-info summary result into your question.