# Is it possible to retrieve the mentioned drives?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, microsoft

My wife tried to install ubuntu as dual with windows and she ended up with this link http://paste.ubuntu.com/11416559/ , you can clearly see that there are 2 Microsoft drives inside sda1. The question is, is there a way to retrieve either those drives or the associated data back?

Answer (score 2):

The "drives" under `sda1` are actually the EFI boot files in your EFI boot partition which allows you to boot Windows on your computer in UEFI mode. These files contain no data from a Windows installation so you would be unable to retrieve anything useful from them and since the normal Windows NTFS partitions were formatted you are unable to boot into Windows using those files either.

Comment: @AhmadHussien If you want to recover data from a deleted NTFS partition you may want to look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/171179/234273) and also [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/286206/234273). These answers cover the step needed to recover data from formatted partitions.