# How to install Windows 7 alongside ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I tried to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7 and it turned out that I booted only Ubuntu. All my data in windows 7 OS are gone. Is there any chance I can retrive those data? And I want to dual boot windows 7 now. How do I do it? If I do it will it be enough for me to get the datas back?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, just try `sudo update-grub` from the terminal and then reboot when it's done. That does the trick in most cases.

Comment: Too broad but relevant posts are [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) and probably [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data)

Answer (score -1):

first try to get your data back, try if you can recover your lost partition with **testdisk** you can install it just by typing in the terminal

`sudo apt-get install testdisk`

it doesn't have a graphical interface so run in terminal by typing `testdisk`
and choose the appropriate hard drive and tell us the results

Answer (score -1):

Well .. the most popular (and safest) way is boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and follow recommended repair.
But there are some chances that it won't work. If that's the case, try using os-prober directly. Os-prober is the tool that does the job of detecting OSes (including windows). Most probably it will already be installed. If not,

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

Next,

```
sudo os-prober
```

Now for next step, you need to know if your partition table is MBR or GPT.
If MBR,

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

if GPT,

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/GRUB/grub.cfg
```

If you can't figure out whether your partition table is MBR or GPT style, look for **/boot/efi/EFI** directory. If it is available, most probably it is GPT.