# Windows 10 will not boot after I deleted partitions

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, ssd

I had win 10 installed on my SSD 240 Samsung hard drive and thought I was installing Ubuntu to my new M.2 hard drive that I just fitted to my Intel NUC to run along side each other.

At one point I was able to load both win 10 and Ubuntu from the Ubuntu boot menu. Then I got a bit carried away and decided to delete the partitions on my SSD Windows 10 hard drive. Since I have done that I cannot boot Windows 10 anymore. Ubuntu says that I only have Ubuntu installed on my computer.

I can see my files on the SSD through Ubuntu but it will not boot or give an option to boot? Can someone help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS. Best to see what is missing: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info But if you deleted Windows Boot partition, then link above to using testdisk should work.

Comment: i ran testdisk last night and it could not find the partitions on the drive. i really don’t know what i have done. i can access the hard drive and see all he windows components on it etc. I ensured it was mounted and have backed up the data on an external hard drive. Would it be best to just format it and re-do?. Oh i did get an error on testdisc where it said "warning bad sectors" or something like that. i will run again and post , thanx

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14403576/                        here is the pastebin, can some one advise why i cant get this to fix?. i have tried installing a new windows via usb but get errors on every copy i try to boot.  by seond hard drive is saying "warning bad sectors when i try and boot into it. I can se al the files via ubuntu file view but i cannot get a windows to work. i dont mind wiping the drive and loading a new version of windows onto it, if only i knew how?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Just burn Boot-Repair into a USB stick and then launch from USB

Comment: i tried that but doesnt work, paste bin above shows details