# Recovering 3 months worth of code

Tags: xubuntu, data-recovery

I tried today to install `xubuntu` on my PC but I had some problems in partitioning, while I was trying to fix it, I accidentally deleted everything from the partitions .

So is it possible to recover from ntfs with Xubuntu .

The data that was on my hard drive exceed 400GB of songs, family photos, my work !!

Comment: ...and no backup? You may be able to recover some of it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data?rq=1

Comment: Well, I tried this and I got a new partition in Gparted which is 697GB in size, but how can I access it ?

Comment: Sounds like you need a data recovery program. Whatever you do don't try to format anything and do not try to create partitions. That will make it worse. I'll see if I can find a decent livecd with data recovery tools on it for you to hopefully get at least some of ti back. EDIT: mikewhatever has things covered. Check that out and see what you can do. Sorry Linux so far hasn't been all that kind to you. Hopefully we can get things sorted out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern, But I tried using testdisk on my old partition . Now when I open Gparted I see that on partition is added with only 15GB used from 694GB, this is the partition that I have my files on, but how can I access it or recover files from it ?

Comment: If there is any livecd for file recovery, I will give it a try .

Comment: [This is my main partition I guess](http://imgur.com/eu7HKyWl.png),
And [this is a screen shot from gparted](http://imgur.com/uwMZi2Nl.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons. If you have a follow-up question that strays to far from the original one, consider [asking a new question](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the comments, I think I can help you solve your issue.

1. Get a live session running from a USB or CD.
2. Open GParted while in the live session ( the drive "/" shouldn't be mounted ).
3. Delete all the partitions on your drive - Do not format them, just delete them from the registry.

   Your data drive was lost and overwritten by your new installation, and for testdisk to recover your data drive, the new, overriding partitions need to be gone. Back up anything that you have on there and delete all the partitions.

   Now because Xubuntu was installed over your data partition (assuming the data partition took up the entire space), there is mostlikely going to be data missing. Hopefully testdisk can recover what you need.
4. Now run testdisk and [recover your data](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) using testdisk. Look for NTFS partition, or whatever type your data partition was earlier. Testdisk WILL find your recently deleted ext4 partition, but you do not want that. You may need to do deep scans to get the data partition back.

If you need more help with this, comment here to let me know.

I have done this before (I dd'd the first hundred or so megabytes of my drive, lost everything, used testdisk to bring it all back), so I've got experience here!

Comment: Thanks so much !   I did what you said it didn't work for me but it gave me a glance to what to do, I  recovered the deleted partition it in ext4 format on xubuntu with TestDisk, then I used PhotoRec to recover all of my files,  I recover 90% of my files and even images and memory that I thought they were totally lost, Thank you so much !