# Undeleting Windows 7 from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, undelete

I have 2 disks: one with Windows and second split into 2 partitions, on one I have Ubuntu and on the second one I have some more space for Windows' files. I've accidentally deleted all Windows' files: both from disk with main system and partition from other and I want to recover them. Using this: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13706/recover-deleted-files-on-an-ntfs-hard-drive-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/ I found out that all or most of the files are still there and I can recover them (well, I haven't written anything on them after deletion so it should be this way I guess), but I wonder if I could recover whole Windows. It would be nice as I don't have Windows key at the moment and need Windows a bit. After some research I've found TestDisk, but I'm not sure if I can recover it with this and how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data) and [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions)

Answer (score -1):

If you manage to restore your Windows registry (stored in `C:\Windows\System32\config`), it should be possible to restore your Windows product key as explained here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-to-recover-your-windows-product-key/f032f08f-f114-46f6-ab81-b28004dd43a0

Then, you can use your Windows product key in the Windows installer that you can download from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Comment: We don't care about Windows and the question is not about that anyway.

Comment: @MichaelBay I think it is. He said that he managed to recover his files and asks "I wonder if I could recover whole Windows" and says he doesn't have his "Windows key".
If it isn't about Windows, what is it about?

Comment: Windows is off topic here. It *should* be obvious. As a courtesy occasionally users do get answer about reinstalling Windows after Ubuntu and/or recovering deleted (Windows) partitions but that's as far as it gets. This is NOT for generic Windows questions or answers. There's SuperUser for that. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic and https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer, namelly *Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are not about Ubuntu as defined in the help center*.